# Setting dynamic delay for Camel file consumer

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi, blueprint, camel-ftp

I want to set the delay for my camel file consumer. I am using blueprint DSL. Not sure how do I set it dynamically.

`<from id="_from1" uri="file:<filepath>?delay=1000&amp;delete=true"/>`

I want the value "1000" to be picked up from a property file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation about using property placeholders: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html it covers how to do that.

Comment: When I try using simple it throws a compile time error.

The parameter delay requires a numeric value.

`uri="file:{{PFlowDir}}{{PFlowIn_AEROW}}?delay=simple{timeout}`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding the correct property placeholder tags {{delay}}.

Using $simple{delay} throws compile time error.